# Cannot access System Status or Find Contacts after upgrade 4.7.19 on Wordpress

Tags: 4.7

I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to access my System Status screen (the warning in footer is "System Status: Error"). I get a 500 error when I try to access some of the Search functions as well: (Find Contacts / Advanced Search etc).

Wordpress 4.7.5, CiviCRM 4.7.19.

I had Debugging/Backtrace turned on, and ran into this:

```
#0 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT civicrm_custom_field.id as civicrm_custom_field_id, civicrm_custom_fie...")
#4 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT civicrm_custom_field.id as civicrm_custom_field_id, civicrm_custom_fie...")
#5 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT civicrm_custom_field.id as civicrm_custom_field_id, civicrm_custom_fie...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:8))
#7 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#8 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT civicrm_custom_field.id as civicrm_custom_field_id, civicrm_custom_fie...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#9 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1054 ** Unknown column 'civicrm_custom_group.is_public' in 'field list'")
#10 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#11 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT civicrm_custom_field.id as civicrm_custom_field_id, civicrm_custom_fie...")
#12 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2446): DB_common->query("SELECT civicrm_custom_field.id as civicrm_custom_field_id, civicrm_custom_fie...")
#13 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1635): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT civicrm_custom_field.id as civicrm_custom_field_id, civicrm_custom_fie...")
#14 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(357): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT civicrm_custom_field.id as civicrm_custom_field_id, civicrm_custom_fie...")
#15 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1307): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT civicrm_custom_field.id as civicrm_custom_field_id, civicrm_custom_fie...", TRUE)
#16 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomGroup.php(537): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT civicrm_custom_field.id as civicrm_custom_field_id, civicrm_custom_fie...", (Array:0))
#17 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php(64): CRM_Core_BAO_CustomGroup::getTree("Individual", Object(CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary), "2", NULL, "")
#18 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.php(87): CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary->preProcess()
#19 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Contact_Page_View_Summary->run((Array:3), NULL)
#20 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#21 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#22 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1227): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#23 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#24 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#25 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#26 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#27 /home/59460-47919.cloudwaysapps.com/nzgxzrukdb/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(222): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#28 {main}
```

Comment: Do you have any extensions enabled?

Comment: Yes. It would appear my SendGrid plugin was the culprit. I should have known to check this out first. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear this was an extension conflict. Thanks, Aidan!

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer.  Could you edit your answer to say a bit more and help other people that might have the same problem?

Comment: Enrico, since the clue that you're thanking me for is a 'comment' rather than an 'answer', you can't 'accept' it but if you hover just to the left of my original comment you should see an arrow to mark that comment as useful.

Answer (score 1):

That looks to suggest you haven't run the database upgrade part yet, you would need to go to http:///wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1 and run the database upgrades

Seamus